# При наведении на элемент курсор не заменяется изображением

Tags: html, css, cursor

Вот css

```
.left_slice:hover {
    cursor: url(btn_left.cur), pointer !important;
}
```

Пути указаны правильно. Картинка btn_left.cur лежит в той же папке что и style.css.
При наведении на .left_slice курсор так и не становится картинкой. Конвертировал btn_left.png по этой ссылке [convertio](https://convertio.co/ru/)

Как исправить эту ошибку.
Вот PNG файл который должен быть на курсоре
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

`:hover`не нужен

```html
<body style="cursor: url(https://webcodius.ru/images/cursor.cur), pointer;">Hello World! Hello World!</body>
```

Comment: Если не получилось, проверьте путь к файлу

Comment: Конвертирую png в cur все равно не получается. Когда вставляю вот эту ссылку на изображение https://webcodius.ru/images/cursor.cur то получается. Свое изображение сделать не могу.